# Remove backslash before forward slash

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

Context:  [GoogleBooks API returing unexpected thumbnail url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226805/google-books-api-returning-unexpected-thumbnail-url)

Ok so i found the reason for the problem i had in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226805/google-books-api-returning-unexpected-thumbnail-url) question

what i found was the returned url from the googlebooks api was something like this:

```
http:/\/books.google.com\/books\/content?id=0DwKEBD5ZBUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api
```

Going to that url would return a error, but if i replaced the "\ /"s with "/" it would return the proper url

is there something like a java/kotlin regex that would change this `http:/\/books.google.com\/` to this `http://books.google.com/`
(i know a bit of regex in python but I'm clueless in java/kotlin)

thank you

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Simple string replace is enough: `s.replace("\\/", "/")`. Note that if "/" char is escaped then other similar chars may be escaped as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triple-quoted string literals (that act as raw string literals where backslashes are treated as literal chars and not part of string escape sequences) + [`kotlin.text.replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html):

```kotlin
val text = """http:/\/books.google.com\/books\/content?id=0DwKEBD5ZBUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api"""
print(text.replace("""\/""", "/"))
```

Output:

```
http://books.google.com/books/content?id=0DwKEBD5ZBUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/TJBGHv).

*NOTE*: you will need to double the backslashes in the regular string literal:

```kotlin
print(text.replace("\\/", "/"))
```

If you need to use this "backslash + slash" pattern in a regex you will need 2 backslashes in the triple-quoted string literal and 4 backslashes in a regular string literal:

```kotlin
print(text.replace("""\\/""".toRegex(), "/"))
print(text.replace("\\\\/".toRegex(), "/"))
```

*NOTE*: There is no need to escape `/` forward slash in a Kotlin regex declaration as it is not a special regex metacharacter and Kotlin regexps are defined with string literals, not regex literals, and thus do not need regex delimiters (`/` is often used as a regex delimiter char in environments that support this notation).

Answer (score 1):

You could match the protocol, and then replace the backslash followed by a forward slash by a forward slash only

```
https?:\\?/\\?/\S+
```

Pattern in Java

```
String regex = "https?:\\\\?/\\\\?/\\S+";
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/uKPEp0) | [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2ZWXQ/1)

For example in Java:

```
String regex = "https?:\\\\?/\\\\?/\\S+"; 
String string = "http:/\\/books.google.com\\/books\\/content?id=0DwKEBD5ZBUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api";
  if(string.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println(string.replace("\\/", "/"));
  }
}
```

Output

```
http://books.google.com/books/content?id=0DwKEBD5ZBUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and my url was:

```
String url="https:\\/\\/www.dailymotion.com\\/cdn\\/H264-320x240\\/video\\/x83iqpl.mp4?sec=zaJEh8Q2ahOorzbKJTOI7b5FX3QT8OXSbnjpCAnNyUWNHl1kqXq0D9F8iLMFJ0ocg120B-dMbEE5kDQJN4hYIA";
```

I solved it with this code:

```
 replace("\\/", "/");
```